# show context menu of notifyicon error

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0, notifyicon

I am trying to show a context menu when i click on the tray icon (mnuLeft for left click and mnuRight for right click)

```
   Private Sub NotifyIcon_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TrayIcon.Click
      If e.Equals(MouseButtons.Left) Then
         TrayIcon.ContextMenuStrip = mnuLeft
      ElseIf e.Equals(MouseButtons.Right) Then
         TrayIcon.ContextMenuStrip = mnuRight
      End If
      TrayIcon.ContextMenuStrip.Show(Control.MousePosition) 'or ContextMenuStrip.Show(Control.MousePosition)
   End Sub
```

and I get the following error (on the ContextMenuStrip.Show line): **NullReferenceException was unhandled**

Can anyone help me out, any alternatives are welcomed...

PS:

.Show(Cursor.Position) >> same error

e.location >> Error 1   'location' is not a member of 'System.EventArgs'

Answer (score 0):

Should you be doing:

```
TrayIcon.ContextMenuStrip.Show(Control.MousePosition)
```

Comment: Have tried setting a brake point and checked that "ContextMenuStrip" and "Control.MousePosition" both have a value? One of your variables is going to be Nothing.

Comment: ContextMenuStrip and TrayIcon.ContextMenuStrip = Nothing

Comment: I only set the value on the click event for the TrayIcon.ContextMenuStrip

Answer (score 0):

```
TrayIcon.ContextMenuStrip=mnuLeft
```

I set the ContextMenuStrip property of the NotifyIcon component and this time worked. Strage, first time it shown no menu, so I removed it, I guess I was too focused on the position and I forgot about this